# How used Autowired with Rest Client Apache CXF config in xml

Tags: java, spring, jax-rs, cxf-client

How used `@Autowired` with configuration xml of Apache CXF JAXRs
I have un client with Apache CXF - JAXRs in file xml of configuration at Spring but when try use `@Autowired` Spring i see exception of (No qualifying bean of type), i need used `@Autowired` with Object only work it

clientCxf.xml

```xml
    <jaxrs:client id="helloWorldService"
        address="http://localhost:8080/"
        serviceClass="com.complement.IHelloWorldService"
        inheritHeaders="true" username="golduser" password="topsecret">
        <jaxrs:headers>
            <entry key="Content-Type" value="application/xml" />
        </jaxrs:headers>
        <jaxrs:features>
            <cxf:logging />
        </jaxrs:features>
    </jaxrs:client>
```

Note: I see this configuration build one Proxy type Object and JAXRSClientFactoryBeanDefinitionParser `@Qualifier(value = "helloWorldService.proxyFactory")`

IHelloWorldService .java

```java
@WebService
@Path("/message")
public interface IHelloWorldService {

    @POST
    @Path("/getMsg")
    public Resultado getMsg(Pregunta pregunta);

}
```

Example `@Autowired`

Not work:

```java
    @Autowired
    private IHelloWorldService helloWorldService;
```

Work:

```java
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("helloWorldService")
    private Object helloWorldService;
```

Note: For this code i need cast interface por example:

```java
IHelloWorldService helloWorldServiceC = (IHelloWorldService) helloWorldService;
```

i tried configurated but not work

```java
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
```

Please help me for used @Autowired configuration xml i dont more need.